# how to get spaces between each and every char when an alphanumeric or a number is identified?

Tags: python, regex

I had a string as folowing:

```
text = "126 2225xx009"
```

and used the following regex expressions to identify:

a) alphanumeric word (`2225xx009`):

```
\b([a-z]+[0-9]+|[0-9]+[a-z]+)[a-z0-9]*\b"
```

b) digit (`126`):

```
(\d+)
```

I am trying the following code snippet to produce spaces between each and every char when a number or an alphanumeric is found.

```
alphanumeric_text = re.sub("\b([a-z]+[0-9]+|[0-9]+[a-z]+)[a-z0-9]*\b", " \\1 ", text)
numeric_text = text = re.sub("(\d+)", " \\1 ", alphanumeric_text )
```

Desired Output:

```
1 2 6 2 2 2 5 x x 0 0 9
```

Comment: you mean your alphanumberic is not `[a-z0-9]+` but by your definition of `([a-z]+[0-9]+|[0-9]+[a-z]+)[a-z0-9]*` ?

Comment: `\\1` repeats the capturing group. How do you expect the spaces to come in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to insert a space between each char of each match. Use `lambda x: " ".join(x.group())` as the replacement:

```
import re
text = "126 2225xx009"
rx_alnum = r"\b(?:[a-z]+[0-9]+|[0-9]+[a-z]+)[a-z0-9]*\b"
rx_digits = r"\d+"
alphanumeric_text = re.sub(rx_alnum, lambda x: " ".join(x.group()), text)
print(alphanumeric_text) # => 126 2 2 2 5 x x 0 0 9
numeric_text = text = re.sub(rx_digits, lambda x: " ".join(x.group()), alphanumeric_text )
print(text)              # => 1 2 6 2 2 2 5 x x 0 0 9
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/knfgxe).

A minor note: `"\b"` (in your code) matches a backspace, not a word boundary. See above, `r"\b"` matches a word boundary.

You may combine the regexps into a single pattern:

```
rx = r"\b(?:[a-z]+[0-9]+|[0-9]+[a-z]+)[a-z0-9]*\b|\d+"
print(re.sub(rx, lambda x: " ".join(x.group()), text))
# => 1 2 6 2 2 2 5 x x 0 0 9
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/e4F8kf).

Comment: I didn't know that we can have lambda function in re.sub() method. That's cool. it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that if you are combining the regexps into a single pattern that it is important to make sure that in the `\d+` alternate pattern looking for digits is tested after the pattern looking for alphanumerics.

Comment: @Booboo Yes, it is important, as when overlapping patterns are ORed, generic ones should come last.

Answer (score 0):

Second argument of `re.sub` might be `str` or *function*, which will receive one argument of type `re.Match`. This object has `.group(0)` which is substring found. Function should return replacement `str`. This should become more clear if you consider example. Lets say that you want spaces solely inside numbers (non-negative integers), then you might do:

```
import re
text = "abc 123 xyz 999"
def func(x):
    return ' '.join(x.group(0))
out = re.sub(r'\b\d+\b', func, text)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
abc 1 2 3 xyz 9 9 9
```

Note that `.group(0)` gives you whole match irrespectively of grouping, so you can use it freely in first argument of `re.sub`.